# how would I go about creating a simple socket.IO chat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I've been looking at socket.IO and I've stumbled upon some problems. I'm trying to create a WebSocket based chat but It seems that I can't find how I would go about creating a chat where the client is hosted on a different server than the socket.io server. I have a PHP based client that needs to connect to the server but I basically want to know how I can connect to a external socket.IO websocket server.

Comment: I'd propose connecting server-side with Javascript, not PHP. That will require reloading the page for each message (if it is even possible). BTW, a client cannot be written in PHP. Normally it is used server-side, that's the point of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow this really great [tutorial](http://vijayannadi.wordpress.com/tutorials/sample-chat-app-using-nodejs-socketio/) to start with.

At this line of code:

```
033 socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
```

Replace with your server address.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll check it out. If it works I won't forget to set your answer as the accepted answer :D